How to pass the path into a method in Spring Shell?
I want the user to input the path to a file as an argument, but it removes the slashes. For example, when the user inputs C:\test.txt inside the fileRead method, I get c:test.txt.
@ShellMethod(value = "Command import your frequency into database. You need pass path to the file .xlsx")
public String fileRead(@ShellOption(defaultValue = "") String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (path.isEmpty() && !path.equals("")) {
        return "You need to pass path to the file";
    }
    return "Successfully read";
}

Is there a way to pass the path as an argument parameter?

How do you pass parameters?

'' often used as escape symbol. Try to use '\' instead.

@talexmovedtoCodidact user input method like file-read path-to-file. This one \ work s. Is there a way without escape symbol ?

I doubt you can avoid escaping . You can try to use / instead,

shouldn't surrounding the path with quotes allow avoiding the escaping?

@asgarov1 I tried and it didn't help.

You need to escape your \. Use \\ instead.
